# How to fInd frequencies of pair of strings within a Unix terminal

Tags: string, unix, terminal, frequency

how can I compute the following from within the Unix terminal and then store the results in a file?

```
4F8D-AA87-D9EC8805DFDA,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b91302add63f7b115
4F8D-AA87-D9EC8805DFDA,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b91302add63f7b115
4F8D-AA87-D9EC8805DFDA,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b9130dsasdadsadss
49FB-A855-3EED46E0BF2E,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b9130dsasdadsadss

4F8D-AA87-D9EC8805DFDA,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b91302add63f7b115, 2
4F8D-AA87-D9EC8805DFDA,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b9130dsasdadsadss, 1
49FB-A855-3EED46E0BF2E,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b9130dsasdadsadss, 1
```

**EDIT:**

OK, I think, I got it:

```
cat lol | cut -f 1,2 -d ',' | sort | uniq -c > lol2
```

My only problem now it is that the fist column of the output file should - in fact - be at the end, and also that the output file should be csv compatible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be a problem to simply count unique lines instead? If not, the `uniq` command is your friend - [see its manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq), but be sure to sort the list first so that all repetitions happen after another:

```
sort myfile.txt | uniq -c
```

For your example data, returns:

```
  2 4F8D-AA87-D9EC8805DFDA,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b91302add63f7b115
  1 4F8D-AA87-D9EC8805DFDA,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b9130dsasdadsadss
  1 49FB-A855-3EED46E0BF2E,3a58538d510c66b98ad7bb3cb9768de08e1ae30b9130dsasdadsadss
```

To redirect into a file, append `> outfile.txt`:

```
sort myfile.txt | uniq -c > outfile.txt
```

If you need an output similar to the one in your question, you can use `awk` to reorder columns and `sed` to change delimiters:

```
sort count.txt | uniq -c | awk '{ print $2 " " $1 }' | sed 's/ /,/'
```